# what means a true conditions when using the bitwise operator

Tags: node.js

Wokring on the port of js code, i face a difficulty while working with bitwise operations.

There is an if condition, which i m not sure i understand fully.

The condition i fail to understand is

```
if (byteUnderConsideration & Math.pow(2, (7 - bitIndexWithinByte))) return node.right
```

I cant figure out when it will be true in that case.

The full original code is,

```
KBucket.prototype._determineNode = function (node, id, bitIndex) {
  // **NOTE** remember that id is a Buffer and has granularity of
  // bytes (8 bits), whereas the bitIndex is the _bit_ index (not byte)

  // id's that are too short are put in low bucket (1 byte = 8 bits)
  // parseInt(bitIndex / 8) finds how many bytes the bitIndex describes
  // bitIndex % 8 checks if we have extra bits beyond byte multiples
  // if number of bytes is <= no. of bytes described by bitIndex and there
  // are extra bits to consider, this means id has less bits than what
  // bitIndex describes, id therefore is too short, and will be put in low
  // bucket
  var bytesDescribedByBitIndex = ~~(bitIndex / 8)
  var bitIndexWithinByte = bitIndex % 8
  if ((id.length <= bytesDescribedByBitIndex) && (bitIndexWithinByte !== 0)) return node.left

  var byteUnderConsideration = id[bytesDescribedByBitIndex]

  // byteUnderConsideration is an integer from 0 to 255 represented by 8 bits
  // where 255 is 11111111 and 0 is 00000000
  // in order to find out whether the bit at bitIndexWithinByte is set
  // we construct Math.pow(2, (7 - bitIndexWithinByte)) which will consist
  // of all bits being 0, with only one bit set to 1
  // for example, if bitIndexWithinByte is 3, we will construct 00010000 by
  // Math.pow(2, (7 - 3)) -> Math.pow(2, 4) -> 16
  if (byteUnderConsideration & Math.pow(2, (7 - bitIndexWithinByte))) return node.right

  return node.left
}
```

The ported code is,

```
func (K *KBucket) determineNode(node *KBucketNode, id []byte, bitIndex int) *KBucketNode {
    if len(id) < 20 {
        panic(fmt.Errorf("id length must be 20, got %v", id))
    }
    // **NOTE** remember that id is a Buffer and has granularity of
    // bytes (8 bits), whereas the bitIndex is the _bit_ index (not byte)

    // id's that are too short are put in low bucket (1 byte = 8 bits)
    // parseInt(bitIndex / 8) finds how many bytes the bitIndex describes
    // bitIndex % 8 checks if we have extra bits beyond byte multiples
    // if number of bytes is <= no. of bytes described by bitIndex and there
    // are extra bits to consider, this means id has less bits than what
    // bitIndex describes, id therefore is too short, and will be put in low
    // bucket
    bytesDescribedByBitIndex := int(math.Floor(float64(bitIndex) / 8))
    bitIndexWithinByte := float64(bitIndex % 8)
    if len(id) <= bytesDescribedByBitIndex && bitIndexWithinByte != 0 {
        return node.left
    }

    byteUnderConsideration := id[bytesDescribedByBitIndex]

    // byteUnderConsideration is an integer from 0 to 255 represented by 8 bits
    // where 255 is 11111111 and 0 is 00000000
    // in order to find out whether the bit at bitIndexWithinByte is set
    // we construct Math.pow(2, (7 - bitIndexWithinByte)) which will consist
    // of all bits being 0, with only one bit set to 1
    // for example, if bitIndexWithinByte is 3, we will construct 00010000 by
    // Math.pow(2, (7 - 3)) -> Math.pow(2, 4) -> 16
    y := int(byteUnderConsideration) & int(math.Pow(2, (7-bitIndexWithinByte)))
    if y > 0 {
        return node.right
    }

    return node.left
}
```

I don t usually perform this kind of computations, this is all unclear, and i fail to properly determine the right way to print them to start make sense of the logic.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if you're working on bits then instead of:

```
x * 8
x / 8
```

maybe do:

```
x << 3
x >> 3
```

which will make the intention more clear.

Also, it doesn't make much sense to use:

```
byteUnderConsideration & Math.pow(2, (7 - bitIndexWithinByte))
```

when you can do:

```
byteUnderConsideration & (1 << (7 - bitIndexWithinByte))
```

Which will be much more clear (not to even mention that it will be much more efficient).

The `<<` operator shifts bits to the left and `>>` shifts to the right.

The `&` operator ANDs the bits on the same position and the `|` operator ORs the bits.

You should really take some time and read about the bitwise operators in JavaScript (which work pretty much the same as in C) because you make a lot of strange constructs like:

```
~~(x / 8)
```

which can be just:

```
x >> 3
```

and the `~~` (negation done twice) would not be needed as you'd already have an integer. Besides even in cases where you need to force a conversion to an integer then instead of doing `~~x` you may be better off doing `x|0` - see the difference between the combined operator `~~` and `|0` here:

- http://asmjs.org/spec/latest/

Comment: Hi, thanks for returns, i will inform the original author about that. If i rephrase under which condition `byteUnderConsideration & (1 << (7 - bitIndexWithinByte))` will be true ?

Comment: @mh-cbon this expression will be true when a given bit counting from the most significant bits to the least significant bits will be 1. For example if byteUnderConsideration is 00001000 then it will be true for (7 - bitIndexWithinByte) equal to 3 so for bitIndexWithinByte == 4. That's because `1<<(7-4)` will be equal to 8 and then ANDed with the tested number will be truthy - i.e. will have some bits set (in this case one bit).